# What's wrong with this Registration stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to make a Registration stored procedure and when I execute the code, I get this error. I've googled it but it's more specific message error was not able to find a solution. what can cause issue here? Thanks in advice!

Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_Registration, Line 39 [Batch Start Line 9]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.

This is my stored procedure:

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Nika Kalatozi>
-- Create date: <04/07/2017>
-- Description: <Registration Stored Procedure>
-- =============================================
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Registration]
    @Username NVARCHAR(25),
    @Password NVARCHAR(30),
    @Email NVARCHAR(35),
    @Firstname NVARCHAR(25),
    @Lastname NVARCHAR(25),
    @Gender NVARCHAR(10),
    @Birthdate DATE,
    @PhoneNumber NVARCHAR(25),
    @PersonalID NVARCHAR(11),
    @Result VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT @Username FROM Users WHERE @Username = @Username)
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = 'The username you have entered is already in use.'
        RETURN;
    END
    ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT @Email FROM Users WHERE @Email = @Email)
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = 'The email you have entered is already in use.'
        RETURN;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Users(Username, [Password], Email, Firstname, Lastname,
                          Gender, BirthDate, PhoneNumber, PersonalID)

        SET @Result = 'You have been registered successfully.'
        RETURN;
    END
END
```

Comment: That's not mysql code. Please drop the mysql tag.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In code

```
INSERT INTO Users(
...
)
```

you should specify what to insert:

```
INSERT INTO Users(
...
) VALUES
(@Username, ...) -- specify values in brakets
```

Comment: Ow thank you very much, didn't mentioned it.
Now I have issue with exception 
System.Exception: 'Problem with Registering Account. Procedure or function SP_Registration has too many arguments specified.' I'm fighting with this exceptions :( 
Here's my Users Table http://prntscr.com/etyc64

Comment: @NikushaKalatozi look carefully at your code where you call procedure - make sure that you didn't loose some arguments in procedure declaration

Comment: Fixed that issue as well, here's new one,
Why should ID Column (which is primary key) should accept nulls? 
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'TestDatabase.dbo.Users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Error converting data type varchar to int.

The statement has been terminated.'

Comment: @NikushaKalatozi from screen I see that your `Id` column type is `nchar(10)`. So I assume it's not auto-generated and you should specify it if you are doing `insert`. If you will use `ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY` then sql server would generate new ID on every insert

Comment: Fixed that as well, but I've got another exception, this is so annoying I had this exception long time ago and I wasn't able to solve it. 
http://prntscr.com/etymcq

Comment: @NikushaKalatozi seems that you need to convert `PersonalId` to int

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140236/discussion-between-nikusha-kalatozi-and-denis-krasakov).